# Custom filter to active admin to extract multiple rows on Index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

I have a working code that filter out one row of if the conditions are met

```
  ransacker :custome_search, formatter: proc { |v|
    user = Util.new(param: v.strip).user. # gets the data from an external service
    id = user.present? ? user.id : nil
    id = id.presence
  } do |parent|
    parent.table[:id]
  end
```

and a filter in my index page as

```
  filter :custome_search, label: 'Custom Data Search:', filters: ['equals']
```

this work fine, but now I have to change this to accommodate multiple tuples
so I changed my code to

```
  ransacker :custome_search, formatter: proc { |v|
    users = Util.new(param: v.strip).find_users
    ids = users.present? ? users.pluck(:id)  : nil # now returns an array instead of just one id  [1,2,3]
    ids = ids.presence
  } do |parent|
    parent.table[:id]
  end
```

the above code displays zero results as the query formed internally comes out to be

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = NULL LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2) subquery_for_count /*controller:users,action:index*/  [["LIMIT", 30], ["OFFSET", 0]]
```

but if I do a

```
ids=ids.first
```

the same will display one row,
how to I change my code to display multiple rows on the index page
I am using active admin 2.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the ransack code was fine, I just needed to change the filter on the index page , any of these would work

```
  filter :custome_search, label: 'Custom Data Search:', filters: ['in']
```

or

```
  filter :custome_search_in, label: 'Custom Data Search:', as: :string
```